# Transparent control over WM Player ActiveX component in .NET

Tags: .net, activex, gdi+, transparency, opacity

I have a Windows media player activex component in my Form. On top of this WM player i have a picturebox with background color set to transparent. When i set an image for this picturebox , thought the image contains transparent areas it is displayed as black when the picturebox is above the WM player component.

Where as if i place the PictureBox somewhere else in the form. The transparent area are rendered properly.

So is there anyway that i  can place a transparent image on top of a WM Player component. (hmm something like watermark may be). I want this picture to be displayed with  may be 50% opacity when the video is playing in WM player control. Will GDI+ be of any use in this case?

Comment: Isn't there any way to do it? No way to render transparent control over media player?

Answer (score 0):

I would try placing a separate, semi-transparent *Form* over the WM Player control.